# Why "close" an already answered question?

Tags: discussion

If a question is asked that is "off-topic" and then gets an answer that OP accepts, what is accomplished by "closed as off-topic"?

It's still there; the question and answer can be read, so has the close accomplished anything at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question can be read. It can also be read that such questions are off-topic, which may cause some of the readers to reconsider asking similar questions in the future.

Closed questions can be deleted if three 10K+ users vote to delete (in rare cases, more than 3 votes are required).

A user's history of asking questions that end up being closed may eventually lead to them losing the asking privilege.